# What is the idea of github, and these .zip files developers sharing there?

Tags: zip, github

I started to experience Ubuntu (again) now years later.

Now Ubuntu is only OS on my laptop and I want to keep it.

I am installing major software for daily things from Software Center already.

For some software, Google sends me to GitHub.

There is some useful apps which are explained by developer directly and if I get it correct, it is for sharing with other developers (which I am not).

There is only option for downloading the product is "Download .zip file".

If I understand correct, it is kind of repository which is familiar for me from Kodi.

So is it possible to install an application from that .zip file I get from GitHub?

To be clear, in my case, I am interested in this tool: [Torum Playlist Editor](https://github.com/torum/Playlist-editor). And downloaded its .zip file.

File is on my desktop with name: Playlist-editor-master.zip

Is there a way to install this app on my Ubuntu by using terminal?

Because I can use same codes for other zip files in future too.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Ask the developer how to compile. The readme says "use this IDE to compile" and nothing else.

Comment: They offer .zip & it applies to all OSes & reduces their running costs (ie. compressed files use less bandwidth). Github's concern is their operation, and not what's easiest for you (the end-user)

Comment: @guiverc: This has nothing to do with GitHub saving cost. Read my answer below: It's about making a well-defined release version available without end users having to become familiar with git tags and the tools to use them.

Comment: Fair enough... I'd still rather get a tarball rather than forcing everyone to use zip.

Comment: Sure, the Linux / Unix world prefers tarballs, but GitHub also caters to the Windows crowd (not only since Microsoft acquired GitHub). ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is an alternative way to get the source code so you can *build* the application yourself. For that you need to follow the instructions that the software author hopefully provided on the project's GitHub main page. Depending on what programming language is used, you'll need to install build tools such as compilers, linkers and header files; the project's documentation should tell you what exactly you need.

If you are more familiar with building software, you might as well check out the sources directly from GitHub with `git clone` and switch to a *tag* that indicates the latest stable version (which the current *git master* may not necessarily be).

The ZIP files are generated when the project *releases* an official version, i.e. when they create a *release tag*. That spares you the trouble of finding out what exactly the latest stable (i.e. recommended) version was, and also having to use the Git tools correctly.